# Pass SQL value to asp.net HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to have a Go Back link which goes to a page using a query string.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="backLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="../project.aspx?id={0}"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I use a `SqlDataReader` elsewhere on my page so decided to use this to grab the ID that I wanted to pass to this hyperlink.  The issue is when I tried to pass the value to this URL I kept getting errors that I was trying to convert int to string and no matter what I tried in converting it, it wouldn't allow me to use it.

I also tried something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="backLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="../project.aspx?id=<%=variableName%>"></asp:HyperLink>
```

That didn't work either.  It literally printed it instead of grabbing the value which might be because it was enclosed in double quotes?

What is the best way to grab an int (Column is configured as an int) from a SQL table and then pass that to asp.net in a way similar to the above?

Comment: You can use a property on your hyperlink object in your code-behind to assign it the url that you read from sql server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code-behind (Page_Load), try this:

```
this.backLink.NavigateUrl = "../project.aspx?id=" + yourID.ToString();
```

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how often problems are resolved with just a single line of code.  That is doing what I wanted, thanks.

Comment: It is always nice when it is something simple, but frustrating too. :-) Please upvote zespri as the comment suggested the same thing I wrote for my answer.